# Using width percentage is not working

Tags: html, css

So I can't seem to have the table cells get to the right width. Could anyone help me with this issue? Changing the width percentage doesn't seem to do anything. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 70%;'>
            <div style="height:70%; width:40%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
            </div>
            <div style="height:70%; width:60%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                kah
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 30%;'>
            <div style="height:30%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to align them next to each other. But the problem is you wrote your cells into different table-rows so it shows them line by line.

Then there is another problem. You cannot use colspan with divs as inline style but you need to make hah in 2 columns width. So you should separate that to a different table.

Final should be like this:

```
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 70%'>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 70%;'>
            <div style="height:70%; width:40%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
</div>
            <div style="height:70%; width:60%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                kah
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>
        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 30%;'>
            <div style="height:30%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell; colspan:2;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the layout you desire using inline-block for the cell divs so that your percentage sizes work and not using display:table because there is no equivalent to colspan in CSS tables. The heights of the cells need to be 100% so they are 100% of the parent row heights. We also need box-sizing:border-box on the cells so that the cell sizes are inclusive of the border size otherwise the cells would not fit in next to each other as the border widths would be added to the cell widths and exceed 100% in the normal content-box layout.

You can view my JSBin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/huxor/4/edit?html,css,output) and I have left it with border colours set so that you can see clearly which div is which.

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row" style='height:70%;'>
        <div class="cell" style="width:40%; border:1px solid red;">
            blah
        </div><div class="cell" style="width:60%; border:1px solid blue;">
            kah
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style='height:30%;'>
        <div class="cell" style="width:100%; border:1px solid green;">
            hah
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {height:100%;}

.table { width:100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid pink; padding:0; margin:0;}

.row { width:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

.cell { display: inline-block; height:100%; clear: none; padding:0; margin:0;box-sizing: border-box;}
```